AngularJs: Backend returned code undefined, Body was: undefined
I'm getting an error of undefined from the Backend but when i got to the swagger and test out my endpoints they are returning data.
I tried to reconfigure the settings to see what might be the problem and to logout the request data
First it was returning data fine then all of a sudden the code does not return any data nor does it show where the problem has occured.
app.module.ts  

 providers: [     // {     //   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,     //   useClass: LoaderInterceptor,     //   multi: true     // },     {       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,       useClass: HttpLoadingInterceptor,       multi: true,     },     {       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,       useClass: MsalInterceptor,       multi: true,     },     {       provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,       useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,     },     {       provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,       useFactory: MsalGuardConfigurationFactory,     },     {       provide: ErrorHandler,       useClass: GlobalErrorHandlerService     },     MsalService,     MsalBroadcastService,     MsalGuard,     SharedService,     MsalService,     MsalBroadcastService,     MsalGuard,     ConfirmationService,      MessageService,     DialogService,     HubServiceService,     InventoryTableService,     HealthcheckService,     ProductService,     provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptorsFromDi(), withInterceptors([       httpCacheInterceptor()     ])),     GetproductsService,     ConfigServiceService,     BackgroundServiceService,     CacheService,     WhmovementService,     HttpService   ],

``

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hub } from '../../Interfaces/hubs';
import { catchError, map, Observable, shareReplay, timeout } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { handleError } from '../../Interceptors/httpErrorHandling';
import { HttpService } from '../Http/HttpService/http.service.service';
import { Endpoint } from '../../endpoint';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HubServiceService {

constructor(
private httpSrv: HttpService
) { }

// Live Http Requests
listHubs(): Observable\<Hub\[\]\> {
return this.httpSrv.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/${Endpoint.hubs}`).pipe(
catchError(handleError),
shareReplay(1),
map((res) =\> {
return res
})
)
};

GetHubInfo(name: string, type: number): Observable\<Hub\> {
console.log("Requesting Hub Info")
let params = new HttpParams().set('hubId', name).set('hubType', type);
return this.httpSrv.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/${Endpoint.hubInfo}`, {params}).pipe(
catchError(handleError),
timeout(3000),
shareReplay(1),
map((res) =\> {
return res
})
)
};

enableHubSync(hubId: string, isSyncEnable: boolean): Observable\<Hub\> {
console.log("Enabling Hub Sales Orders")
let params = new HttpParams().set('HubId', hubId).set('IsSyncEnabled', isSyncEnable)
return this.httpSrv.put(`${environment.baseUrl}/${Endpoint.activateHub}`, {}, {params}).pipe(
catchError(handleError),
timeout(5000),
shareReplay(1),
map((res) =\> {
return res
})
)
};

}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';
import { GetproductsService } from '../../../Services/products/getproducts.service';
import { HubServiceService } from '../../../Services/hub/hub-service.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home-dahsboard',
templateUrl: './home-dahsboard.component.html',
styleUrl: './home-dahsboard.component.css'
})
export class HomeDahsboardComponent implements OnInit {
itemCount!: number;
hubsCount!: number;
messages!: Message\[\];

constructor(
private products: GetproductsService,
private hubs: HubServiceService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.products.getProducts().subscribe(
{
next: itemLen =\> this.itemCount = itemLen.length,
error: e =\>  this.messages = \[{ severity: 'error', detail: `${e}` }\]
}
);

    this.hubs.listHubs().subscribe(
      {
        next: hub => this.hubsCount = hub.length,
        error: e =>  this.messages = [{ severity: 'error', detail: `${e}` }]
      }
    );

}
}

{
"/api": {
"target": "http://localhost:7845",
"secure": false,
"changeOrigin": true,
"logLevel": "debug"
}
}


What is the raw HTTP response you are getting back?

Literally nothing :Backend API returned undefined

Undefined is the response in JavaScript. Use the browser Dev tools network tab to obtain the raw HTTP response. If you have control over the API you are calling, you can debug there as well.
